# Run multiple queries on a report

Tags: ms-access

I've got a monthly report that is generated from data recorded each day. At the bottom of the report I have Sum, Min, Max, and Avg for certain fields.

I need to be able to also get data from the last day of the previous month to display at the top of the report, but this data cannot be included in the Sum, Min, Max, and Avg.

I'm assuming that this means I must run 2 separate queries and am unsure of how to do to this properly. I'm also curious if it might just be easier to run VBA on report Open to subtract from the earliest day in the query results and display the data that way.

What is going to be the easiest method to achieve these results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA would work, but I think this is a better case for a subreport.

In the design view of the report, you should have a subreport tool.  Drag and drop that, then set your source to the other query results you wish to display.